# Setting homedrive via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I’m trying to make a visual studio app script to make users in active directory. It was all working fine until I tried to set the path of the users home drive and set the path to `H:` can anyone shed some light into why this isn't working please?

```
   Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
    Dim Command As String

    'creating home diretorys'
    Command = "mkdir \\bw-file-01\student$\EY{year}\APPTesting"
    Command = Replace(Command, "{year}", Year.Text)
    MsgBox("Direcotry has been made in" & Year.Text & "file path")

    'setting up account'

    Command = "dsadd user ""cn={fstname}.{lstname},ou=New_users,ou=students,ou=users," & _
      "ou=Broadwater School,dc=broadwater,dc=surrey,dc=sch,dc=uk"" " & _
      "-disabled yes -pwd password -mustchpwd yes -desc {desr} -email {fstname}.{lstname}@broadwater.surrey.sch.uk -upn ""{fstname}{lstname}@broadwater.surrey.sch.uk"" " & _
      "-fn ""{fstname}"" -ln ""{lstname}"" -Display ""{fstname} {lstname}"""


    Command = Replace(Command, "{fstname}", Firstnamebox.Text)
    Command = Replace(Command, "{lstname}", Surnamebox.Text)
    Command = Replace(Command, "{desr}", desr.Text)
    Command = Replace(Command, "{year}", Year.Text)

    MsgBox("Account has been made in the" & Year.Text & "group")


    Command = "Set-ADuser -Identity $_ -HomeDrive {homedrive} -HomeDirectory {filepath}"

    Command = Replace(Command, "{homedrive}", "H:")
    Command = Replace(Command, "{filepath}", "\\bw-file-01\student$\EY2014\AppTesting")

    MsgBox("Home folder has been set up")

    Shell("cmd /c" & Command, 1, True)

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to use VBScript or VB.NET? Looks like a reviewer may have added the [VBScript] tag to this post (probably because you used the phrase "Visual Basic script" in your question). You code is clearly VB.NET, though. Which are you looking for?

Comment: Rabbit ears missing? `Replace(Command, "{homedrive}", """H:""")`

Comment: Its a visual studio app / script and im confused what am I replacing?